# SharePoint context menu differs despite of same permissions

Tags: 2010, document-library

I have 2 people added having same permissions but both of them see different count of items in the Actions context menu of a document library.

**Connect to Outlook** and **Sync to computer** options seems to be missing.

What can be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that there is a difference with their Office installation maybe something is not installed correctly on the user with the missing options.

I would get the user with the missing options to login on to the same machine as the user with the visible options and see if those items appear.

I would also check the permission level and make sure that the user with missing option has the permission "Use Client Integration"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the difference in IE versions. In older browsers, these options come in the context menu whereas the newer browsers have them in the ribbon at the top.